# Insert an array into linked list with elements in random order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random, linked-list, shuffle

I have an array, say: `books[10]`,
and a linked list, say: `bookList`.

I want to insert all elements in `books[10]` into the linked list, but in an random order.

Solution 1:
Shuffle the array, then insert from 0 to length-1.

Solution 2:
Insert from 0 to length-1 as-is, then shuffle the linked list.

Solution 3:
Generate a Fisher–Yates shuffled array of `indexArray= {0, 1, 2, ..., length-1}`, then insert the element in that order into the linked list:

```
for(i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i ++)
   bookList.add(books[indexArray[i]]);
```

Currently I'm using 1 as it seems to be the easiest, I think solution 3 would be better if object in my array is big since I don't have to shuffle the original array but an int array for index instead.

Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to kind-of combine methods (1) and (3):

(For a reference see the "The modern algorithm" section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle.)

- Iterate an index `i` from `n` down to `1` (using 1-based indexing).
- At each step, pick a random number `m` between `1` and `i`.
- Insert the element of the array at index `m` to the front of the linked list.  (We will build the list back-to-front, although actually it makes no difference if you decide to insert entries at the back of the list instead.  Building back-to-front lets you avoid keeping track of a pointer to the back of the list, to avoid `O(n)` insertion time resulting from scanning to the end at each step.)
- Move the element of the array at index `i` to the slot at index `m`.

This avoids a small amount of the overhead of an in-place shuffle, avoids the memory overhead of generating an array of indices, and avoids a complicated in-place shuffle of a linked list associated with method (2).  It runs in `O(n)` time, using `O(1)` extra memory (ignoring the memory used for the original array and the linked list).

**Edit:** I think actually that the algorithm I describe above should be the easiest to implement by-hand out of the three options you have.  Unless your array is very big the real-life run-time and memory-usage differences of the options you have will probably be negligible.

If the sizes of the entries in the array are indeed quite large, this algorithm suffers from the same problem as an in-place shuffle does, namely having to move big data sets around, and in this case probably generating a list of indices is better.